# Why can't i use external header?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I created a "Cocoa Touch Static Library" and it builds just fine. Peachy so far. Then I created a view based application for iOS. I can import the header from my previously created lib, but I can't run the program. It's always returning:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GenericList", referenced from:

objc-class-ref in Hello_World_2ViewController.o"
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is GenericList one of the classes from your library? If so, it seems like you're not actually linking against your library. It's not enough to reference a header file to use a library in a C program.

Comment: Yep, when I add a library to a project it usually takes 10-15 minutes of futzing to get it recognized.  (And unfortunately I do it just rarely enough that I can never remember what the secret handshake is.)

Comment: @Sii pls tell me what i have to do to actually link against a lib!

Comment: @Leonardo See my answer. Somewhat unfortunately, Obj-C development is also C development, and C (and other native languages) split the build process into compilation and linking, each of which has to be set up separately. The OS X abstraction to make this easier is "frameworks", but you can't create your own frameworks on iOS – I think you're generally meant to share code between your projects by just including the source code files.

Comment: Also, via [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004817/how-do-i-create-an-iphone-framework-and-use-it-in-other-iphone-applications): [an article on sharing code between iPhone projects](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/), and [another one with a Ruby tool to help with this](http://blog.costan.us/2009/02/iphone-development-and-code-sharing.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're not linking against the actual library files, just somehow referenced the header file. Three20 is a popular third-party iOS library, and they have [a documentation article on how to add it to your project](http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project) – look lower on the page for "Manually add Three20 to your project" and adapt the process for your library by skipping any steps that aren't applicable.

Alternately, I'm also guessing that drag-and-dropping the library's .h and .a files into your app's project might Just Work.