# iOS Custom Framework Development?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6

I am trying to create a framework since I am developing a library.

I have Googled a lot, but didnt find any proper tutorial to create. Please give me some suggestions and steps to be followed to create a iOS framework.

I am Using iOS 6 and XCode 4.5.

Comment: This may help:https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework
Read description.

Comment: following links may be helpful

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065052/how-to-build-a-framework-or-library-for-other-developers-the-secure-way
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004817/how-do-i-create-an-iphone-framework-and-use-it-in-other-iphone-applications

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this framework tutorial](http://codefriend.blogspot.com/2011/09/creating-ios-framework-with-xcode4.html) with a lot of success. My callout from the tutorial is that it doesn't specifically mention (from what I recall) building the target, then the bundle before archiving the bundle. I also found it easier to directly copy the archived bundle from its source directory instead of relying on the script.